# Spring boot actuator adding request body in trace throws HttpMessageNotReadableException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Using Spring boot actuator trace, I am trying to add trace with request & response body. I have followed the post [How to include JSON response body in Spring Boot Actuator's Trace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35848802/how-to-include-json-response-body-in-spring-boot-actuators-trace) and created a RequestTraceFilter class without using logback. But if I make a request, then I get an exception in console "Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing:"

Also, swagger-ui.html cannot load once I add this filter.

Did I miss something in the below class?

```
@Component
public class RequestTraceFilter extends WebRequestTraceFilter {

private static final String RESPONSE_BODY = "resBody";
private static final String REQUEST_BODY = "reqBody";

public RequestTraceFilter(TraceRepository repository, TraceProperties properties) {
    super(repository, properties);
}

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
    ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
    filterChain.doFilter(requestWrapper, responseWrapper);
    request.setAttribute(REQUEST_BODY, getRequestBody(requestWrapper));
    request.setAttribute(RESPONSE_BODY, getResponseBody(responseWrapper));
    super.doFilterInternal(requestWrapper, responseWrapper, filterChain);
}


private String getRequestBody(ContentCachingRequestWrapper request) {
    ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrapper = WebUtils.getNativeRequest(request, ContentCachingRequestWrapper.class);
    String characterEncoding = wrapper.getCharacterEncoding();
    return getPayload(wrapper.getContentAsByteArray(), characterEncoding);
}

@Override
protected Map<String, Object> getTrace(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Map<String, Object> trace = super.getTrace(request);
    Object requestBody = request.getAttribute(REQUEST_BODY);
    Object responseBody = request.getAttribute(RESPONSE_BODY);
    if(requestBody != null) {
        trace.put(REQUEST_BODY, (String) requestBody);
    }
    if(responseBody != null) {
        trace.put(RESPONSE_BODY, (String) responseBody);
    }
    return trace;
}

public String getPayload(byte[] buf, String characterEncoding) {
    String payload = null;
        if (buf.length > 0) {
            try {
                payload = new String(buf, 0, buf.length, characterEncoding);
            }
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
                payload = "[unknown]";
            }
        }
    return payload;
}

private String getResponseBody(ContentCachingResponseWrapper response) {
    ContentCachingResponseWrapper wrapper = WebUtils.getNativeResponse(response, ContentCachingResponseWrapper.class);
    return getPayload(wrapper.getContentAsByteArray(), wrapper.getCharacterEncoding());
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse();` [took from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39935190/contentcachingresponsewrapper-produces-empty-response).

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
    ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
    filterChain.doFilter(requestWrapper, responseWrapper);
    responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse();
    request.setAttribute(REQUEST_BODY, getRequestBody(requestWrapper));
    request.setAttribute(RESPONSE_BODY, getResponseBody(responseWrapper));
    super.doFilterInternal(requestWrapper, responseWrapper, filterChain);
}
```